# Finding Quartz Crystal Datasheets and Choosing resistors for Pierce Oscillators

Tags: oscillator, crystal, oscillation

I am trying to build a 2Hz oscillator using a CD4060 IC and a 32.768kHz quartz crystal for a digital clock project. The schematic below is from a [hackersbench article](http://www.hackersbench.com/Projects/1Hz/). I've circled the part i'm interested in. I'm trying to find the optimal value for R1. A common bit of advice given is to consult the datasheet for the quartz crystal when selecting resistor and capacitor values etc etc..  I have not been able to find a data sheet for the crystal I have, nor have I been able to find a similar data sheet for ***any*** similar crystal.

[image: schematic]

[This is the crystal I ordered off amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07Z3V4FMC)

There is some information:

Features:
Type1:
Frequency: 32.768KHz, 12MHz
Body Size: 2 x 6mm / 0.08" x 0.24" (D*L)
Type2:
Frequency: 32.768KHz, 8MHz, 16MHz
Body Size: 3 x 8mm / 0.12" x 0.31" (D*L)
Load Capacitance: 12.5pF

Frequency Tolerance : ±20ppm
Mounting Type: DIP
Number of Pins: 2
Operating Temperature Range: -20℃~70℃
Material: Quartz; Color: Silver Tone

I could simply go with this schematic and hope for the best but i'd really like to understand what i'm doing before I solder things instead of just going by some internet article like an amatuer. I have no idea how he was able to calculate those resistors.

I was able to find this: http://www.ti.com/lit/an/szza043/szza043.pdf
Page 12 explains some of the workings of the oscillator, but doesn't go into much detail on actually calculating anything.

My biggest concern is the crystal breaking after prolonged use. I will be using a trimmer cap to adjust the actual frequency to be close to 2Hz.

This seems to be a pretty popular question on here, and it seems to be a pretty involved subject, probably beyond my junior level knowledge. The author of the article does not mention the specs of the crystal.

**EDIT**: I figured it out and will post my own answer once i test it. The only thing i still need to calculate is the parallel resistors to the crystal. Most sources say “somewhere between 1M and 15M” but i find that sketchy

Here’s what found in the meantime:

https://www.crystek.com/documents/appnotes/pierce-gateintroduction.pdf

Comment: 10M is pretty common and only self biases DC  but R1 is usually > 3k to limit current density in motional capacitance of Xtal not 300k.

Comment: Isn’t it supposed to be equal to the reactive capacitance of C1?

Comment: No the phase shifting is all done by the CLC equivalent circuit, this is purely to limit power (eg 10uW)

Comment: So if my supply voltage is 5v, how do I calculate the limiting resistor?

Comment: And the bigger question is why do so many schematics use such large resistors in 100k?

Comment: Show me a good source that does this. ..It depends on gain margin of oscillator too

Comment: http://www.ti.com/lit/an/szza043/szza043.pdf Page 13: “Acceptable results can be accomplished by choosing the value to be approximately equal to the capacitive reactance”

Comment: That is true for high frequency Xtals but low frequency ones can operate even without any Rs as the 32kHz have a sufficiently high ESR of 50k +/-20k but they forgot to tell you about that

Comment: But I could be wrong and some 32kHZ Xtals (MEMs vs Tuning Forks) require 1uW max so 200kOhms is OK

Comment: https://www.microchip.com/wwwAppNotes/AppNotes.aspx?appnote=en520645

Comment: I can’t find the data sheet for these amazon crystals anywhere (at least in English).. But I did find this crystal data sheet from another 12.5pF crystal from adafruit https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/product-files/2211/2211datasheet.pdf Lists 1.0 micro-watt, looks very similar to my crystal.. Where it says “series resistance: 30k”... Could that be referring to Rs?

Comment: That is the ESR, that I spoke about 50k+/-20k

Comment: Well the circuit is oscillating much better. Currently at 47k Rs  (the lowest I have). Does “30k MAX” indicate that I should be below 30k?

Comment: ESR is a quality value where lower is better for gain margin If the Gain is insufficient (unbuffered) and the Rs added is too high , it fails to oscillate

Comment: I’m sorry i’m a beginner at this stuff. Is ESR like the resistance of the crystal itself? The 4060 data sheets seem to always show the crystal with a limiting Rs.

Comment: ESR is the effective series resistance of any dielectric like any capacitor or battery so Rs is the correct term but also often used for Rsource resistance external to FETs. So I prefer ESR